# How to scroll the back pages with undetected-chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I used undetected-chromedriver to access website, and used JS code to scroll page as below.

```
js = 'window.scrollBy(0,100)' 
webdriver.execute_script(js)
```

It worked for the font pages but failed for those fully covered by other window, especially when I turned off the monitor(code is deployed on server), it failed even for the front pages.

But the above code worked when I used the standard selenium or seleniumbase.
I have no idea why it occurred and how to fix it.

I've tried scrolling page in different way as below, it failed as well.

```
webdriver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'body')[0].send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: why not to just Adjust the Scroll Amount by `js = 'window.scrollBy(0,500)'`

Comment: SeleniumBase has an undetected-chromedriver mode (`--uc`), so you could use that since SeleniumBase works for you. UC Mode video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dMFI3e85ig